# Load a .env file with PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm currently coding on a pure PHP project and I need to load an .env file to get some variables. After a bit of searching I turned to the vlucas/phpdotenv plugin (That I imported with Composer), but I can't import it! Do I have to use an MVC model for this to work?

index.php:

```
<?php
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();
```

bdd.php:

```
<?php

    function DBConnect() {
        $user = getenv("DB_USER");
        $pass = $_ENV["DB_PASSWORD"];
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/tree/master/src/Parser

Comment: Where is the error exactly? Do you get an error when importing the module or is $_ENV empty?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forgot to add `require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');` to your `index.php`

**.env**

```
USER_NAME='jfBiswajit'
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

// Looing for .env at the root directory
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// Retrive env variable
$userName = $_ENV['USER_NAME'];

echo $userName; //jfBiswajit
```

Answer (score 44):

The solution I found for loading a local `.env` file and getting variables:

```
$env = parse_ini_file('.env');
$header = $env["HEADER"];
```

It works for my `.env` file that looks like this:

```
HEADER="Location: /profile"
```

Comment: to be clear - it won't work when values in your `.env` are not quoted("") :)

Comment: @jave.web It works with values not quoted. At least on PHP v8.2

Comment: @AmirhosseinKarimi for basic letter chars yes, but once it contains something extra - e.g. `=` in a DB connection string, then it has to be quoted :-)

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use native `putenv` and `getenv` php functions. The method allows you to use the default value if the value is not defined.

```
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $envFilepath = "$root/.env";
    
    if (is_file($envFilepath)) {
        $file = new \SplFileObject($envFilepath);

        // Loop until we reach the end of the file.
        while (false === $file->eof()) {
            // Get the current line value, trim it and save by putenv.
            putenv(trim($file->fgets()));
        }
    }
    
    // example
    $envValue = getenv('ENVIRONMENT', 'default value');
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Why use a library if you can implement the same functionality with 5 lines of code?**

**.env**

```
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
```

**index.php**

```
$env = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/Directory/.env");
$lines = explode("\n",$env);

foreach($lines as $line){
  preg_match("/([^#]+)\=(.*)/",$line,$matches);
  if(isset($matches[2])){
    putenv(trim($line));
  }
}
```

Explaination:

1. Get the .env file content
2. Create an array of lines
3. Loop through the lines
4. Ignore lines starting with "#" or don't have a value after "="
5. putenv

**bold.php**

```
$host = getenv('DATABASE_HOST');//returns: localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

v5 has changed even further; Use `createUnsafeImmutable` in place of `createImmutable`

> The Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable and Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable
> methods no longer call will result in getenv and putenv being called.
> One should instead use Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable and
> Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeMutable methods, if one really needs these
> functions.

Here is the [guide](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) for upgrading